# manyToOne and oneToMany in hibernate&spring

Tags: java, spring, oracle, hibernate, many-to-one

I have 2 tables in database side(oracle)

```
create table GROUPS
(
  ID   NUMBER not null,
  GROUP_NAME VARCHAR2(30)
)alter table GROUPS
  add constraint ID primary key (ID)
```

and

```
create table ITEM_GROUP
(
  ITEM_ID VARCHAR2(30) not null,
  GROUP_ID    NUMBER not null
)

alter table ITEM_GROUP
  add constraint ITEM_GROUPD_ID primary key (ITEM_ID, GROUP_ID)

alter table ITEM_GROUP
  add constraint ITEM_GROUP_FK01 foreign key (GROUP_ID)
  references GROUPS (ID);
```

Than I have mapping classes in Java side. I want to make thing, when I am selecting group to take all his items too, and I want to save item with hibernate it is all .

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "GROUPS")
public class Group {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID", nullable = false)
    @javax.persistence.SequenceGenerator(name = "groupIdGenerator", sequenceName = "GROUP_SEQ", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "groupIdGenerator")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "GROUP_NAME")
    private String groupName;

    @JsonManagedReference
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy="group",cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<GroupItems> groupItems = new ArrayList<>();
    // setters and getters 

}


@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Embeddable
public class GroupItemPK implements Serializable {

    @Column(name = "ITEM_ID")
    private String merchantId;

    @Column(name = "GROUP_ID")
    private int id;
    // getters , setters , constructors , equals  hashcode methods

}



@Entity
@Table(name = "ITEM_GROUP")
public class GroupITEM {

    @EmbeddedId
    private GroupITEMtPK id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "ID")
    @JsonBackReference
    private Group group;
}
```

I am interested in did i make any mistakes in build relationship ? If I did what is my mistakes , because I can not do my select and save queries without exceptions.

I am trying to do in my Code

```
List<Group> list = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from Group a").list();
```

and  here is my `Exception`

```
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper could not extract ResultSet [n/a]
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00904: "GROUPITE0_"."ID": invalid identifier
```

Comment: No evident error as far as i can see, maybe add what you are trying to to do in code and the exception raised

Comment: Did you try with  @JoinColumn(name = "GROUP_ID") as this is the column in your db that has the reference to group?